# Replace the first zero with 1 within a string -derived column SSIS

Tags: ssis, business-intelligence

I have a string value such as "000030", I would like to replace the first "0" with 1 within a derived column transformation

What is the expression for that?

Any suggestions?

Thanks!
Dre

Comment: Have you researched or tried anything?  Running into any errors or an unexpected result? I would look at the substring function, you could just easily concatenate "1" with a substring of your variable starting at position 2.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

Replace(SUBSTRING("000030",1,1),"0","1")+SUBSTRING("000030",2,6)

Comment: doesn't this assume the 0 is in the first position?

Comment: it doesn't assume 0 in first position but it does assume to replace only 0 with 1 since Replace function is only looking for 0 in first position. Example : Replace(SUBSTRING("500030",1,1),"0","1")+SUBSTRING("500030",2,6) will always return original value 500030